# How Long Does Tomato Juice Last?

Tags: storage-lifetime, tomatoes, juice

We've been buying tomato juice in smaller containers and now decided to buy bigger ones.  But, when we went to the store the tomato juice says that it only lasts two weeks in the fridge.  Expiration dates always err on the side of caution.  How long can we expect to keep it after we have opened it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/18516) website, 5 to 7 days in the fridge.

Answer (score -1):

No more than a week-ish, then it will start growing fungus on the top of the juice.